# Displaying numbers in tkMessageBox

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a python script (on my Linux box with Python 2.7.6 ) in which I enter a company name, a contact name, their phone number and a comment. When I have entered the information I click a button which then opens a file for reading and iterates through it to see if either the company name or phone number are already in the file before appending the data I have entered to the file. If either or both have already previously been logged i want it to display this fact in a tkMessageBox showing, for example, that the phone number is logged 3 times.
It all works except that the number is completely wrong. If the real count is 3 it will show all sorts of numbers maybe 426 or 105 or any other number.below is the part of the code as I have it at present:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Tkinter import *
import time
import tkMessageBox
from ScrolledText import *
titles = 'Company', 'Contact', 'Tel', 'Comments'
fields = 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4'

def show_entry_titles():
    countname = IntVar    
    counttel = IntVar    
    filename = "callers.txt"
    myfile = open(filename, 'r') 
    company= e1.get()
    tel=e2.get()
    for myline in myfile:
        q = myline
        if q.find(company):
            countname += 1
        if q.find(tel):
            counttel += 1
    myfile.close()

    if countname + counttel > 0:
        msg = "Company " + str(countname)
        tkMessageBox.showinfo(countname)

    localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
    localtime = "Logged on: " + localtime + "\n"
    company = "Company " + e1.get() + "\n"
    contact = "Contact " + e2.get() + "\n"
    tel = "Tel Num " + e3.get() + "\n"
    comm = "Comments: " + e4.get('1.0', END+'-1c') + "\n"
    filename = "callers.txt"
    myfile = open(filename, 'a')
    myfile.write(localtime)
    myfile.write(company)
    myfile.write(contact)
    myfile.write(tel)
    myfile.write(comm)
    myfile.write("-----------------------------------\n")
    myfile.close()
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e2.delete(0,END)
    e3.delete(0,END)
    e4.delete('0.0', 'end')
master = Tk()

for k in range(4):
    Label(master, text=titles[k]).grid(row=k)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)
e3 = Entry(master)
e4 = ScrolledText(master, width=40, height=10)
e1.insert(20,"")
e2.insert(20,"")
e3.insert(20,"")
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
e4.grid(row=3, column=1)

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=k+1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_titles).grid(row=k+1, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

As an example with the code as posted I know the particular phone number I entered was already in the file 7 times but the message was:

```
closed file 'callers.txt', mode 'r' at 0x7f870074c0c0
```

With the tkMessageBox line as:

```
tkMessageBox.showinfo(msg)
```

the message comes out as :

```
Company 174
```

I have spent hours searching for a solution but cannot find any reference to displaying a string and an int correctly and I must have tried at least 5 different syntax suggestions.
Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: What is e1.get() and e2.get()? There are multiple problems with your script it looks like, is this the full program? This shouldn't even run...

Comment: e1 and e2 are Entry boxes in which I have typed the Company name and phone numbers

Comment: Where are they defined? It's difficult to help with only a snipped of the code

Comment: I have edited the original code so you can see the whole script

Comment: I have now updated the code here so you can see what I am using now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is 186 instead of 7, because of these lines:

```
    if q.find(company):
        countname += 1
    if q.find(tel):
        counttel += 1
```

You should not use `str.find` in this way. `find` returns -1 if the string is not found, and the index of the start of the substring otherwise. `bool(someInt)` evaluates to `True` for any integer other than zero, so your `countname` and `counttel` will be incremented for every single line in your file, except ones that start with a company name or telephone number. If you want to check if a string is inside another string, I suggest the `in` operator.

```
    if company in q:
        countname += 1
    if tel in q:
        counttel += 1
```

---

As a simpler example, this is effectively what you're doing:

```
lines = [
    "Hello, how are you today?",
    "Today I went to Starbucks and bought a coffee.",
    "It was delicious."
]

countname = 0
company = "Starbucks"
for line in lines:
    if line.find(company):
        countname += 1

print "We found the company name 'Starbucks' this many times: " + str(countname)
```

Result:

```
We found the company name 'Starbucks' this many times: 3
```

This is the incorrect result. 'Starbucks' only appears once, not three times. Let's try again using `in`.

```
lines = [
    "Hello, how are you today?",
    "Today I went to Starbucks and bought a coffee.",
    "It was delicious."
]

countname = 0
company = "Starbucks"
for line in lines:
    if company in line:
        countname += 1

print "We found the company name 'Starbucks' this many times: " + str(countname)
```

Result:

```
We found the company name 'Starbucks' this many times: 1
```

This is the correct result.

Comment: @Parker  Thanks for your efforts. As you will all no doublt see i am a real beginner with Tkinter.

Comment: @smoothgrips Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 2):

I've never used Tkinter before, but a quick Google search shows us that IntVar is a class and when you instantiate classes in Python, you need to use parentheses, like so:

```
countname = IntVar()
counttel = IntVar()
```

When you want to set a value to the object, you use the *set* function, like so:

```
countname.set(0)
```

When you want to retrieve a value from the object, you use the *get* function, like so:

```
countname.get()
```

Also, you declare countname to be an IntVar(), but in the very next line, you set that object to a regular int, so it's no longer an IntVar().

Perhaps the following code will fix your problem:

```
countname = IntVar(0)
counttel = IntVar(0)
...
if q.find(company):
    countname.set(countname.get() + 1)
if q.find(tel):
    counttel.set(counttel.get() + 1)
...
msg = "Company " + str(countname.get())
tkMessageBox.showinfo(countname.get())
```

Sources:

[Tkinter.IntVar](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.IntVar-class.html)

[Tkinterbook: The Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Comment: Well this looked to make sense but the output was 186 for countname wjth this syntax. I added a print statement after the tkMessage Box line and ran the code from a terminal and the print also gave 186 for countname even though the text file only shows 12 now.

Comment: I have edited the original code so you can see the whole script.

Comment: Did you remove the `countname = 0` and `counttel = 0` lines that were after the `countname = IntVar()` and `counttel = IntVar()` lines respectively?

Comment: Yes I did. I have now updated the code here so you can see what I am using now.

Comment: While everything you have said about IntVars in this post is factually correct, I don't believe it has anything to do with the OP's problem. Whether you use IntVars or ordinary integers, the output will be the same. All other things being equal, you may as well use ordinary integers, since their syntax is simpler.